# Prove the invariant property $d(u+w,v+w)=d(u,v)$ of quasi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, invariance

Let $d(.,.)$ be a metric on a vector space $U$ such that $d(u,0)$ defines a quasi norm $\|.\|$, show that

$$d(u+w,v+w)=d(u,v)$$
for all $w\in U$

if $\|\alpha_n u\|\rightarrow 0$ as $\alpha_n\rightarrow 0$ and $
\|\alpha u_n
\|\rightarrow 0$ as $u_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: It is a quasi norm

Comment: $w$ is any vector

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: It is just a random real number not related to the norm?

Comment: Yea, It is a random number.

Comment: Doesn't "$\|\alpha_n u\| \to 0$ as $\alpha_n \to 0$" follow from the quasinorm axioms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. I've been spending 3 hours trying to prove a false theorem.

Let $U = \Bbb R^2$ and $d$ be the [French metro metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrenchMetroMetric.html):
$$d(\vec a,\vec b) = \begin{cases}
|\vec a - \vec b| & \exists c \in \Bbb R: \vec a = c \vec b \\
|\vec a| + |\vec b| & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now, the norm induced by the metric:
$$\|\vec a\| = d(\vec a,0) = |\vec a|$$

Put $\vec u = \vec 0$, $\vec v = \vec i$, and $\vec w = \vec j$:
$$d(\vec u+\vec w,\vec v + \vec w) = d(\vec i,\vec i+\vec j)= 1+\sqrt 2 \ne 1 = d(\vec 0,\vec i) = d(\vec u,\vec v)$$